# Java org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor not found

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to run a project in Eclipse that uses java RMI, but when I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:  
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
```

The asm-3.1.jar library is already in the project classpath and if I try to import the class 
org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor, it is correctly seen. Thus, the problem appears a runtime.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

**Edit (Eclipse classpath file):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/asm-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/asm-analysis-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/asm-commons-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/asm-tree-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/asm-util-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/asm-xml-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/java-cup-11a.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jdom.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jmockit_B.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jode-1.1.2-pre1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/junit-4.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/junit-4.9b2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ModifiedClasses.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/tools.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/uispec4j-2.4-jdk16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/uispec4j-jdk6-2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Probably at runtime you are using a JRE with a version < than what used when compiling the jar

Comment: No, this is not possible since I'm using the latest 1.7 JRE.

Comment: could you post the classpath you are using at runtime, when running the rmi server?

Comment: Yes, I have just added the content of my Eclipse classpath file to my first post. Do you see anything weird there?

Comment: How do you run your app? With an Eclipse run configuration? If yes, you should add to the runtime classpath configuration the jars (check its "Open launch configuration")

Answer (score 0):

Add the jars needed at runtime to the Eclipse's Run classpath configuration. Click either on "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs" buttons:

[image]